# How can I ignore the submit input in a PHP foreach loop

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to create a PHP foreach loop that automatically loops through and retrieves submitted any form data. The problem is:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) { if(!empty($value)) echo $key. “ - “. $value.”<br>”;
```

will also print out the final

```
<input type=“submit” name=“foo” value=“bar”>
```

input, which I want to ignore.

This works if I change from input to button tag, however I prefer to keep input tag. Ta.

Comment: You could always remove the "name" from the input tag. But really why do you care if it's a button or input? There's minimal practical difference, except in this case such differences as do exist would solve your problem...don't make like more complicated unless you have an actual reason rather than a vague whim

Comment: How about use an array `name="data[something]"` for the inputs you want to loop, then you can loop `$_POST['data']`

Comment: P.s. if you're blindly collecting all form data then, depending on what you then do with it afterwards there's a danger, in some circumstances, of leaving your code open to over-posting attacks. Just something to be aware of, as I say it depends on the exact situation whether such a problem would in fact exist

Comment: If you can already manage to write a condition that only makes it output something when the `$value` is not empty, then you should be able to add a second condition that checks whether `$key` is not equal to one specific string value, no ...?

Answer (score 0):

For get all Get And Post Fields From Request

```
public function getAll()
{
   $request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
   $data = [];
        if ($request === 'GET') {
            foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_GET, $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            }
        }
        if ($request === 'POST') {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $data[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
            }
        }
        return $data;
}
```

For take only non empty fileds..do..inside foreach loop

```
if(!empty($value))
{
  $data[$key] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, $key, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);  
}
```